# Do you need extra sockets to have 3-way communication?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, networking

I have a client/server connection over TCP using `send()` and `recv()`.  This is working in full duplex just fine.  However, if I want a 3rd party to be able to join in mid session and communicate on this line, how is it accomplished?  Do I need another socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need a second socket. TCP socket are connection oriented, so they are useful only to manage a single connection beetwen 2 hosts.

Typically you can use a socket open on a well known port to use for establish connection from clients to the server. Then, once the connection has been established, you can transfer it to another socket.

Comment: Only a 3rd?  If I wish to broadcast messages to both user A and user B, as well as receive messages from user A, do I only need one extra socket?

Comment: @cellpho; you need a socket for every bidirectional communication channel. So if you have 2 client and one server you need at least 2 sockets opened in the server. Unless you switch to UDP, of course, but UDP is certainly harder to manage.

Comment: @0verbose thanks for your help.  Obviously, these would have to be on the same port still, correct?  Just wnat to make sure I'm on the right track!  Also, I wouldn't have to wait for both connections to finsih before moving forward?  I could have the second socket be connected mid-session without having to multithread it?

Comment: @cellpho: every socket must use a different port

Comment: @0verbose: Can these be set up without having to multithread, where the extra socket can connect at an arbitrary later time?  Or do you ahve to wait for both to connect?

Comment: @cellpho: if I understood your question: to handle non-blocking function call (read/write) on a socket in order to manage multiple connection at the same time. this is it? you can use thread or select function, but this is another argument. If you are not familiar with network applications and concurrency related problem, i'll suggest you to use select because it simpler.

Comment: @0verbose: Basically, the main communication is occurring between 2 people, which I have right now.  However, a passive 3rd party should be allowed to enter and observe the communications passively, with one user updating the passive user with updates.  I want the 3rd party to be able to enter mid-communications, rather than setting up all of the sockets at the start.

Comment: @cellpho: from my point of view try to avoid threads and use select ( http://linux.die.net/man/2/select ) . Anyway this is a different subject. If you desire a complete answer please read the linked man page and post another question.

Comment: @0verbose I asked a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532747/how-to-get-a-new-socket-connection-mid-session

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't restricted to TCP, [IP multicast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_multicast) and other protocols layered on top of it could be an option depending on your application.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to use UDP, which is connectionless.  Each datagram will contain the sender.  It's up to you, however, to construct a meaningful stream of conversation out of the unordered, unreliable datagrams.

Comment: The last part may prove to be very non-trivial